# How to combine module 'ffi', 'node-windows' on websocket server in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows-services, node-ffi, node-windows

I want to make a websocket server. It can run automatically as a windows service (I use module 'node-windows') and load a file dll (I use module 'ffi').

Here is code in file server.js

```
    var http = require("http");
    var ws = require("../../");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var ffi = require("ffi");

    var server = ws.createServer(function (connection) {
        connection.on("text", function (str) {
            var Lib = ffi.Library('add.dll', {'Add' : ['int',['int','int']]});
            var arr = str.split(":");
            var result = Lib.Add(Number(arr[0]), Number(arr[1]));
            connection.sendText(result);        
        });
    });
    server.listen(8081);
```

And here is code in file install.js. It will set the file server.js to run as a windows service

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

var svc = new Service({
  name:'websocketServer',
  description: 'a simple websocket server',
  script: require('path').join(__dirname,'server.js'),
  env:{
    name: "NODE_ENV",
    value: "production"
  }
});

svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

When I run it, I don't know why but the windows service stops automatically. If I don't use 'ffi', the server will run fine. Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there anything in the Event Log?

Comment: Where is it and how can i check it?

Comment: Use the Windows Event Viewer, it should be in the admin utilities (or accessible by running eventvwr.msc IIRC at least on Windows 7).

Comment: I checked, It have 2 warnings  http://i.imgur.com/52C6LyQ.png, http://i.imgur.com/IidyMQe.png and 1 error:   http://i.imgur.com/pnpl6WX.png

Comment: Before running it as a service run it as a normal application. Also move the `var Lib = ...` line to before the `var server = ...` so it will run faster and make it easier do debug if the error is there.